# Date periods in clojure

Tags: vector, clojure

I have a data structure like this:

```
[{ :2007-08-05 [ { :meat-weight-gain 100} {:meat-weight-loss 80} {:meat-balance 20}]}, 
 { :2007-08-06 [ { :meat-weight-gain 10} {:meat-weight-loss 60} {:meat-balance -30}]},
 { :2007-08-07 [ { :meat-weight-gain 40} {:meat-weight-loss 80} {:meat-balance -70}]}
 { :2007-08-08 [ { :meat-weight-gain 100} {:meat-weight-loss 0} {:meat-balance 30}]}]
```

How can i iterate through it and return the data period of when the meat balance was negative? A sample data would be something like this:

```
[ {:end-period-balance -70, :period-start 2007-08-06, :period-end 2007-08-07 } ]
```

Other than that, can I improve my data structure or it is already ok? If yes, how? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i would advice you to change your data shape to a list of tuples, each containing date and map of balance data. Just like this:

```
(def data [[:2007-08-05 { :meat-weight-gain 100 :meat-weight-loss 80 :meat-balance 20}], 
           [:2007-08-06 { :meat-weight-gain 10 :meat-weight-loss 60 :meat-balance -30}],
           [:2007-08-07 { :meat-weight-gain 40 :meat-weight-loss 80 :meat-balance -70}]
           [:2007-08-08 { :meat-weight-gain 100 :meat-weight-loss 0 :meat-balance 30}]
           [:2007-08-09 { :meat-weight-gain 19 :meat-weight-loss -20 :meat-balance -10}]])
```

then it would be easy to classify the periods by weight gain/loss (using `partition-by`) and collect needed info:

```
user> (let [parts (partition-by #(-> % second :meat-balance neg?) data)]
        (keep #(let [[p-start _] (first %)
                     [p-end {balance :meat-balance}] (last %)]
                 (when (neg? balance)
                   {:period-start p-start
                    :period-end p-end
                    :end-period-balance balance}))
              parts))

;;=> ({:period-start :2007-08-06, :period-end :2007-08-07, :end-period-balance -70} 
;;    {:period-start :2007-08-09, :period-end :2007-08-09, :end-period-balance -10})
```

or a list of maps including date:

```
(def data [{:date :2007-08-05 :meat-weight-gain 100 :meat-weight-loss 80 :meat-balance 20}, 
           {:date :2007-08-06 :meat-weight-gain 10 :meat-weight-loss 60 :meat-balance -30},
           {:date :2007-08-07 :meat-weight-gain 40 :meat-weight-loss 80 :meat-balance -70}
           {:date :2007-08-08 :meat-weight-gain 100 :meat-weight-loss 0 :meat-balance 30}
           {:date :2007-08-09 :meat-weight-gain 100 :meat-weight-loss 0 :meat-balance -10}])

user> (let [parts (partition-by #(-> % :meat-balance neg?) data)]
        (keep #(let [{p-start :date} (first %)
                     {p-end :date balance :meat-balance} (last %)]
                 (when (neg? balance)
                   {:period-start p-start
                    :period-end p-end
                    :end-period-balance balance}))
              parts))

;;=> ({:period-start :2007-08-06, :period-end :2007-08-07, :end-period-balance -70} 
;;    {:period-start :2007-08-09, :period-end :2007-08-09, :end-period-balance -10})
```

**UPDATE**

if you really need your initial data format, then you can use the same approach, just redefining values retrieval parts:

```
user> (defn meat-balance [rec]
        (some :meat-balance (-> rec first second)))

user> (let [parts (partition-by #(-> % meat-balance neg?) data)]
        (keep #(let [p-start (-> % first ffirst)
                     p-end (-> % last ffirst)
                     balance (-> % first meat-balance)]
                 (when (neg? balance)
                   {:period-start p-start
                    :period-end p-end
                    :end-period-balance balance}))
              parts))
;;=> ({:period-start :2007-08-06, :period-end :2007-08-07, :end-period-balance -30})
```

Comment: Your answer was amazing but I really need it following the data i currently have

Answer (score 0):

First of all the complex input data structure can be disentangled:

```
(map (juxt ffirst (comp first #(keep :meat-balance %) val first)))
;;=> ([:2007-08-05 20] [:2007-08-06 -30] [:2007-08-07 -70] [:2007-08-08 30])
```

... into tuples of `[date-keyword meat-balance]`.

Notice that so far we are keeping both positive and negative *meat balances*. The answer requires negative *runs* i.e. contiguous negative meat balances. `partition-by` is the *go to* function for any kind of *run*, after which we can filter to get only the partitioned groups required for the answer. And before anything we need to `sort` because your date keys were originally in a map and maps are unsorted. After sorting, partitioning and filtering we are ready to deliver the answer, which simply entails transforming our canonical `[date-keyword meat-balance]` data structure into the required structure:

```
(->> data
     (map (juxt ffirst (comp first #(keep :meat-balance %) val first)))
     (sort-by first)
     (partition-by #(-> % second neg?))
     (filter #(-> % first second neg?))
     (map (fn [neg-run]
           (let [[start-date _] (first neg-run)
                 [end-date end-value] (last neg-run)]
             {:period-start start-date
              :period-end end-date
              :end-period-balance end-value})))
;;=> [{:end-period-balance -70, :period-start 2007-08-06, :period-end 2007-08-07 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the format of the data:

- Consolidate the vector of data for each date into a single map
  .
- Make the whole thing a map, keyed by the date keywords.
- Lose the `:meat-weight-balance` data - it's redundant.

(The first two changes follow [@leetwinski's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44235958/1562315))

We get ...

```
(def data
  {:2007-08-05 {:meat-weight-gain 100, :meat-weight-loss 80},
   :2007-08-06 {:meat-weight-gain 10, :meat-weight-loss 60},
   :2007-08-07 {:meat-weight-gain 40, :meat-weight-loss 80},
   :2007-08-08 {:meat-weight-gain 100, :meat-weight-loss 0}})
```

The entries happen to be in date order, because it's a small map. If we want to ensure date order, we'd better have a sorted map:

```
(def sorted-data (into (sorted-map) data))
```

This doesn't look any different, but will always present the data in key order, which is - thankfully - date order.

This seems a long way round to get the records into the original order in the vector, but the vector has the unused date-keyword order cutting across it: *D*on't *R*epeat *Y*ourself.

Let's calculate the daily balances:

```
(def balances
  (map-vals #(- (:meat-weight-gain %)  (:meat-weight-loss %)) sorted-data))

balances
=> {:2007-08-05 20, :2007-08-06 -50, :2007-08-07 -40, :2007-08-08 100}
```

... where the `map-vals` function is an analogue of `map` and `mapv` that works on the values of a map:

```
(defn map-vals [f m]
  (into (empty m) (map (fn [[k v]] [k (f v)])) m))
```

Notice that it returns the same species of map as it's given, in this case a sorted one.

We want to know over what periods there was a net weight loss. It isn't clear what this means. Let's look at the net weight gains from the start:

```
(reductions (fn [[_ av] [k v]] [k (+ av v)]) balances)
=> ([:2007-08-05 20] [:2007-08-06 -30] [:2007-08-07 -70] [:2007-08-08 30])
```

Or we could partition the sequence into gaining and losing sections:

```
(partition-by (fn [[_ v]] (neg? v)) balances)
=> (([:2007-08-05 20]) ([:2007-08-06 -50] [:2007-08-07 -40]) ([:2007-08-08 100]))
```

We need a variant of `partition-by` that keys its sub-sequences by the value of the discriminating function, as `group-by` does. Then you know what's a gaining range and what's a losing one. A cheap and cheerful version is ...

```
(defn group-partition-by [f coll]
  (let [parts (partition-by f coll)]
    (map #(-> % first f (list %)) parts)))
```

Then

```
(group-partition-by (fn [[_ v]] (neg? v)) balances)
=> ((false ([:2007-08-05 20]))
    (true ([:2007-08-06 -50] [:2007-08-07 -40]))
    (false ([:2007-08-08 100])))
```

You might want to reduce this data to a (sorted) map from date-range to total balance.

---

*Conversion*

How do we get from `given` to `data`? We can get to `sorted-data` directly as follows:

```
(def sorted-data
  (->> given
       (into (sorted-map))
       (map-vals (comp #(into {} %) #(remove :meat-balance %)))))

sorted-data
=>
{:2007-08-05 {:meat-weight-gain 100, :meat-weight-loss 80},
 :2007-08-06 {:meat-weight-gain 10, :meat-weight-loss 60},
 :2007-08-07 {:meat-weight-gain 40, :meat-weight-loss 80},
 :2007-08-08 {:meat-weight-gain 100, :meat-weight-loss 0}}
```

*Impressions*

- You have to get to know the [sequence library](https://clojure.org/reference/sequences#_the_seq_library) thoroughly.
- Corresponding facilities for maps aren't on the surface. Getting to
  grips with [transducers](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers) would help - not sure how much.

---

*Note*

You had better be using European, not American dates, otherwise you are going to need a cleverer `keyfn` to get the records in date sequence. I'd prefer [`clj-time`](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) `local-date`s to keywords as keys

- in case the code crosses the Atlantic;
- so that you can run validity checks, such as that you have a record
  for every day.

Answer (score 0):

As it already has been said above, your data are not structured well for such a purpose. Here is a step-by-step solution:

Prepare your data:

```
(def data
  [{ :2007-08-05 [ { :meat-weight-gain 100} {:meat-weight-loss 80} {:meat-balance 20}]}, 
   { :2007-08-06 [ { :meat-weight-gain 10} {:meat-weight-loss 60} {:meat-balance -30}]},
   { :2007-08-07 [ { :meat-weight-gain 40} {:meat-weight-loss 80} {:meat-balance -70}]}
   { :2007-08-08 [ { :meat-weight-gain 100} {:meat-weight-loss 0} {:meat-balance 30}]}])
```

Create a new data structure:

```
(defn turner [stats]
  (apply merge
         {:year (-> stats keys first)}
         (-> stats vals first)))

(def data2 (mapv turner data))

[{:year :2007-08-05, :meat-weight-gain 100, :meat-weight-loss 80, :meat-balance 20}
 {:year :2007-08-06, :meat-weight-gain 10, :meat-weight-loss 60, :meat-balance -30}
 {:year :2007-08-07, :meat-weight-gain 40, :meat-weight-loss 80, :meat-balance -70}
 {:year :2007-08-08, :meat-weight-gain 100, :meat-weight-loss 0, :meat-balance 30}]
```

Now you group your data by a predicate that check whether the balance was negative or not:

```
(partition-by #(-> % :meat-balance neg?) (sort-by :year data2))

(({:year :2007-08-05, :meat-weight-gain 100, :meat-weight-loss 80, :meat-balance 20})
 ({:year :2007-08-06, :meat-weight-gain 10, :meat-weight-loss 60, :meat-balance -30}
  {:year :2007-08-07, :meat-weight-gain 40, :meat-weight-loss 80, :meat-balance -70})
 ({:year :2007-08-08, :meat-weight-gain 100, :meat-weight-loss 0, :meat-balance 30}))
```

Let it be `data3`. Then, filter that data structure to get only negative ones:

```
(filter #(-> % first :meat-balance neg?) data3)

(({:year :2007-08-06, :meat-weight-gain 10, :meat-weight-loss 60, :meat-balance -30}
  {:year :2007-08-07, :meat-weight-gain 40, :meat-weight-loss 80, :meat-balance -70}))
```

Let it be `data4`. Now you get the boundaries:

```
{:period-start (-> data4 first first :year) 
 :period-end (-> data4 first last :year) 
 :end-period-balance (-> data4 first last :meat-balance)}
```

what gives you exactly

```
{:period-start :2007-08-06, 
 :period-end :2007-08-07, 
 :end-period-balance -70}
```